# C11 VLA matrix access

Tags: c, dynamic, matrix

C11 permits to use VLA array (and matrices) like

```
int row = 10;
int col = 10;
double matrix[row][col];
```

but if i want to pass to a function only a row of the matrix can i use

```
matrix[row_selected]
```

as if i had defined matrix as

```
double **matrix_old_style = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * row);
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
matrix_old_style[i] = (double *)malloc(siezeof(double) * col);
```

or matrix[row_selected] is not a pointer to the correct location (like matrix_old_style[row_selected])?

Comment: No, they are not the same at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 2D arrays and pseudo arrays through pointers to pointers are not the same at all.

To pass a VLA as function parameter simply do

```
void foo(size_t n, size_t m, double A[n][m]);
```

or similar. Note the sizes come before the array, so `n` and `m` are known at that point. If you use that notion consistently, the compiler will take care of index calculations and so on.

Note though, that usually you don't want to allocate such beasts as `auto` variables since they might explode your stack. Better use

```
double (*matrix)[col] = malloc(sizeof(double[row][col]));
```

When you pass it to a function, this type is what the compiler rewrites it, anyhow, when using it as a function parameter.

Comment: @AndreaOliveri, if this answers your question, please click on the button to accept it, so it changes "state" to sucessfully answered.

Answer (score -1):

of course you can,look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun(int a[6])
{
    cout << a[3] << endl; 
}
int main()
{
    int a[5][6];
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
            a[i][j]=i+j;

    cout << a[2][3] << endl;
    cout << *(*(a+2)+3) << endl;
    fun(a[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

the three output is the same!

Comment: The question is not for C++,